# common values between two call statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql

the problem is, I have a procedure which returns a set of values and the column name returned by that procedure is friend, it accepts 1 parameter that is username,
now I have two queries:
`call test('nishchal')` and `call test('nootan')` now I want the common values returned by these two procedure, any solution guys??

My procedure has these lines of codes

```
begin 
select u_name` as friend 
from table_name 
where f_id = username 
end
```

where username is the parameter passed

Comment: What do the procedures do?  Can you not construct some SQL to obtain your desired results from the underlying data?  Stored procedures don't really return anything, they just execute other commands, so it's quite difficult to work with arising resultsets from within SQL.

Comment: my procedure has these lines of codes, 
`begin
select `u_name` as `friend` from table_name where `f_id` = username
end
where username is the parameter passed

Comment: But then, by definition, no results can be common across your two procedure calls unless both calls are made with the same parameter value.  That is, no record in `table_name` can simultaneously have `f_id='nishchal'` and `f_id='nootan'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit clunky but you could put the results into a temporary table.